# If $G = VN$, $V$ a four group and $N$ regular normal, then there exists some Sylow subgroup left invariant by $V$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a permutation group on $\Omega$ with $G = VN$, where $V \cong C_2 \times C_2$ (the four-group) and $N$ has odd order with some prime divisor $>3$. Suppose $N$ is a regular normal subgroup.

> There exists some prime $p \ne 3$ and a Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ of $N$ which is left invariant by $V$.

Do you know any proof of this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$I think the following more general result is true.

Let $G = P N$ be a group, where $P$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$, $N$ is a $p'$-group, and $N$ is normal in $G$. Then for each $q$ dividing the order of $N$, there is a $q$-Sylow subgroup of $N$ normalized by $P$.

Let $\Delta$ be the set of $q$-Sylow subgroups of $N$, and let $Q$ be one of these subgroups. The size of $\Delta$ is $\lvert N : N_{N}(Q) \rvert$, a $p'$-number.

Now $P$ acts by conjugation on $\Delta$. But not all orbits can have an order which is a multiple of $p$, otherwise the order of $\Delta$ would be divisible by $p$.

So there is an orbit $\{ Q \}$ of length 1, and thus $P$ leaves $Q$ invariant.

---

Or alternatively, fix a $q$-Sylow subgroup $Q$ of $G$. Then the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups is
$$
\Size{N : N_{N}(Q)}
=
\Size{N : N \cap N_{G}(Q)}
=
\frac{\Size{N \cdot N_{G}(Q)}}{\Size{N_{G}(Q)}}
=
\Size{G : N_{G}(Q)},
$$
so that $G = N \cdot N_{G}(Q)$. It follows that $N_{G}(Q)$ contains a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, that is, a conjugate of $P$. Back-conjugating you get that $P$ normalizes a $q$-Sylow subgroup of $N$.

Comment: Thank you! Just a minor comment: In your last paragraph I guess you mean "[...] a $p$-Sylow subgroup $H$ of $G$ [...]" and not "[...] a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$ [...]".

Comment: You're welcome! And, thanks, I have fixed the typo.

Comment: By the way, the second part is the Frattini argument.

Comment: Just a question, in your first proof you need the normality to deduce that $P$ acts on $\Delta$. But in your second proof I do not see where the normality enters into the argument, or isn't it needed here (and then the result also holds for non-normal $N$)? EDIT: Yes, for Frattini normality is also essential. But the equations you wrote also hold for non-normal subgroups as I see it...

Comment: I have used normality implicitly when I say the all the $q$-Sylow subgroups are contained in $N$, that is, when I say $\Size{N : N_{N}(Q)} = \Size{G : N_{G}(Q)}$.